# Why am I getting this error when I try to put a custom color?

Tags: c#, colors

When I try to make a custom color I get an error

Code:

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb (127, 255, 212);
```

When I use

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.c;
```

I get an error

> "c" is not a valid color

Comment: Hi Mate, ConsoleColor will allow you selecting predefined colours. For using a custom color ou can just assign the newly created color.

Console.ForegroundColor = c;

Answer (score 2):

The console can accept colors only from the `ConsoleColor` enum. You cannot assign a custom color, unfortunately.

You must use code like this:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
```

For a comprehensive list of colors, look here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.consolecolor

Comment: I throw an error if I put it like this (Google Translator)

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Status deleted
Error CS0029 Implicitly cannot convert type 'System.Drawing.Color' to 'System.ConsoleColor'

Comment: Having the error means everything. It tells you specifically why the code isn't compiling. Please see my revised answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `ConsoleColor` enum and `Drawing.Color` class are sadly two different things. The second is only for WinForms use. The Console has only the preset colors. More information about the colors console uses can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors). About the `ConsoleColor` enum, take a look at [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.consolecolor?view=netcore-3.1). And for `Drawing.Color` take a look at [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color?view=netcore-3.1).